# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException even after adding dependency entry

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, dom4j

I'm getting this exception while deploying my war.

```
Caused by: **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException**
    at com.findmybuddy.restws.utils.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:13)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException**
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    ... 49 more
```

I have added dom4j dependency entry in pom.xml also

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I don't known why I'm getting this exception still.

Comment: Have you cleaned an reinstall your war?

Comment: Is the dom4j.jar present in the generated WAR file?

Comment: Make sure dom4j.jar is in the classpath.

Comment: Open your war file by using unzip tool and check in lib whether dom4j jar is available or not.